# Can't see response headers from Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, response

I am using 3rd party SMS billing system.

When I get a GET request from that system I need to send back some data using header.

My controller:

```
  if @billing.present? && @advertisement.present?


                     @payment = Payment.new
                        @payment.identifier = @advertisement.identifier
                        @payment.sms_id = sms_id
                        @payment.operator_id = operator_id

                        @payment.from = from
                        @payment.to = to
                        @payment.billing_id = @billing.id
                        @payment.advertisement_id = @advertisement.id
                        @payment.content = text

                    @payment.save




                    response.headers["x-esteria-price"] = @billing.price


                   flash[:notice] = "Īsziņa satur pakalpojuma kodu =  #{code} identifikātors = #{identifier} .Charged = #{charged} Pirmais pieprasījums !!! "

                else
                   params[:answer] = "Atvainojiet, Jus neesat noradijusi lietotajvardu (login)SMS teksta. Uzmanigi parbaudiet  nosutito tekstu!"
                   params[:price] = 0.10 #???         
                            response.headers["x-esteria-price: 0.10"]  #jānorāda ka nepareizi dati !! ATBILDES ZIŅA UN CENA
                   flash[:notice] = "NEIZDEVĀS. Trūkst pakalpojums vai attiecīgais sludinājums.Atvainojiet, Jus neesat noradijusi lietotajvardu (login)SMS teksta. Uzmanigi parbaudiet  nosutito tekstu!"
                end
```

I have tried:

```
response.headers["x-esteria-price: #{@billing.price}"]
```

this don't give me anything in Chrome Network/Headers panel:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
ETag:"a3c16129b9bd85f4fb98a5a839865823"
Server:thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
Set-Cookie:country_id=1; path=/
Set-Cookie:_Proj_session=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--c3e31e1f5d82414800255d77725197037d887cf6; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:5c1f2c42-80c5-4613-ba8c-2ad14d6e116e
X-Runtime:0.493049
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

and

```
response.headers["x-esteria-price"] = @billing.price
```

this gives me internal server error, but without any further explanations.

My development.log

```
Started GET "/sms/receive?sms-id=7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab&operator-%20id=1&from=37126300682&to=371144&text=ILR3+30895" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-11 22:39:42 +0200
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`[0m
Processing by SmsController#receive as HTML
  Parameters: {"sms-id"=>"7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab", "operator- id"=>"1", "from"=>"37126300682", "to"=>"371144", "text"=>"ILR3 30895"}
  [1m[35mCountry Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  `countries`.* FROM `countries`  WHERE `countries`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM `advertisements`  WHERE (country_id=1) AND (vip_recomend >= '2015-02-11 22:39:42')[0m
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `advertisements`  WHERE (country_id=1) AND (recomend >= '2015-02-11 22:39:42')
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM `advertisements`  WHERE (country_id=1) AND (highlight >= '2015-02-11 22:39:42')[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `advertisements`  WHERE (country_id=1) AND (vip_highlight >= '2015-02-11 22:39:42')
  [1m[36mList Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `lists`.* FROM `lists`  WHERE (billing_id =4)  ORDER BY `lists`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mList Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  `lists`.* FROM `lists`  WHERE (billing_id =5)  ORDER BY `lists`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `lists`.* FROM `lists`  WHERE (billing_id =5)  ORDER BY `lists`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mList Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  `lists`.* FROM `lists`  WHERE (billing_id =3)  ORDER BY `lists`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBilling Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `billings`.* FROM `billings`  WHERE `billings`.`name` = 'ILR3' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mAdvertisement Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  `advertisements`.* FROM `advertisements`  WHERE (identifier = '30895') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `payments` (`advertisement_id`, `billing_id`, `content`, `created_at`, `from`, `identifier`, `sms_id`, `to`, `updated_at`) VALUES (85, 4, 'ILR3 30895', '2015-02-11 22:39:43', '37126300682', 30895, '7bb28e244189f2cf36cbebb9d1d4d02001da53ab', 371144, '2015-02-11 22:39:43')
  [1m[36m (39.8ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  Rendered sms/receive.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
  [1m[35mBanner Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  `banners`.* FROM `banners`  WHERE (country_id = 1)  ORDER BY `banners`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBanner Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `banners`.* FROM `banners`  WHERE (country_id = 1)  ORDER BY `banners`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mAdvertisement Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  `advertisements`.* FROM `advertisements`  WHERE `advertisements`.`id` = 85  ORDER BY `advertisements`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRegion Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `regions`.* FROM `regions`  WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 1[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `regions`.* FROM `regions`  WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 1
  Rendered shared/_drop.html.erb (30.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_drops.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_age_warning.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered messages/_form.html.erb (14.4ms)
  Rendered offers/_form.html.erb (6.9ms)
  [1m[36mType Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `types`.* FROM `types`[0m
  Rendered feedbacks/_form.html.erb (20.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_login.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 680ms (Views: 503.5ms | ActiveRecord: 58.1ms)
```

Then in Chrome Console I have this message: ***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)***

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're attempting to set headers so you can use them in your frontend client? With the line `response.headers["x-esteria-price"] = @billing.price` what are the logs/backtrace associated with the 500 error?

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the error. You can find the error in log file

Comment: @LeoCorrea I updated my question with some logs.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds those don't seem to be the complete logs. Notice the Rails server is saying you've processed the #receive action with a HTTP 200 and rendered the receive.html.erb. Usually when you receive a 500 on the browser it means an exception was thrown in the server and you'll see the specitic stacktrace of that error.

Comment: @LeoCorrea That is all I got from development logs. In browser I got regular text in left side 'Internal server error'

Comment: Can you show the controller code that is displaying that view and where you're setting the header?

Comment: @LeoCorrea I updated my question with controller part which produces that error.